# R: difficulties generating orthogonal polynomials between 0 and 1

Tags: r, polynomials, orthogonal

I'm trying to do some regression on variables with the interval [0,1]. I'd like to include orthogonal quadratic and cubic components. The polynomials I am after are [Shifted Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials)(Wikipedia).

I am baffled by the behaviour of the poly() function in R. 
Not only does it not return a vector in [0,1], the vector it *does* return varies with the length of the input vector.

This code generates an illustrative example. The code generates some first-order polynomials (lines) from x. The intervals of the resultant polynomials range from [-0.36,0.36] to [-0.017,0.017].

```
x <- seq(0,1,by = 0.1) # base variable
plot(x,x,col=2)

M<-matrix(nrow=6,ncol=4)
dfpoly<-data.frame(M)

v<- c(0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001,0.0005,0.0001) # This vector alters the length of x

for (i in 1:length(v)){
    x <- seq(0,1,by = v[i])
    y <- poly(x,degree = 3)[,1] #first order polynomial, should in my mind be the same as x
    points(x,y)
    dfpoly[i,1] <- length(x)
    dfpoly[i,2] <- min(y)
    dfpoly[i,3] <- max(y)
    dfpoly[i,4] <- mean(diff(y)/diff(x))
    }
names(dfpoly) <- c("x length","y min","y max","y slope")
dfpoly
```

[graph of x vs generated first order polynomials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhINQ.png)

Summary of outputs:

```
  x length          y min         y max       y slope
1       21 -0.36037498508 0.36037498508 0.72074997016
2      101 -0.17064747029 0.17064747029 0.34129494057
3      201 -0.12156314064 0.12156314064 0.24312628128
4     1001 -0.05469022724 0.05469022724 0.10938045447
5     2001 -0.03870080906 0.03870080906 0.07740161813
6    10001 -0.01731791041 0.01731791041 0.03463582082
```

Now, I'd expect all the lines to inhabit the same interval [0,1] as x, and perfectly overlap with x (the red series of points) on the graph. But they don't. Nor do they have any pattern to them that I can identify by eye.

**1. What is the cause of the weird interval behaviour with poly()?**

**2. Are there other techniques or functions I can use to coerce these polynomials to [0,1]?**

Comment: Good catch with the slope. I'm not saying that x should be orthogonal to the first-order polynomial, I'm saying it ought to be the same.

Comment: You need to read my question more carefully. I am not asking why x is not orthogonal to the polynomial y, I am asking why x and y inhabit different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `poly()` function returns a matrix, whose columns are the values of polynomials evaluated at the values of `x`.  From the help page `?poly`, the columns are mutually orthogonal, and are also orthogonal to the constant polynomial `p(x) = 1`.  Orthogonality is in the vector sense (i.e. $\sum x_i y_i = 0$).

I don't think the help page guarantees this, but in practice it appears that the columns are also unit length, i.e. $\sum x_i^2 = 1$.

The unit length condition explains your "weird interval behaviour".  More terms means they have to be smaller to still have a sum of squares equal to 1.

To coerce the columns to the range `[0,1]`, just subtract the minimum and divide by the range.  This will lose both the orthogonality and unit length properties, but
will keep the degree and linear independence.

For example,

```
x <- seq(0,1,by = 0.1) # base variable
plot(x,x,col=2)

M<-matrix(nrow=6,ncol=4)
dfpoly<-data.frame(M)

v<- c(0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001,0.0005,0.0001) # This vector alters the length of x

for (i in 1:length(v)){
        x <- seq(0,1,by = v[i])
        y <- poly(x,degree = 3)[,1] #first order polynomial, should in my mind be the same as x
        y <- (y - min(y))/diff(range(y))
        points(x,y)
        dfpoly[i,1] <- length(x)
        dfpoly[i,2] <- min(y)
        dfpoly[i,3] <- max(y)
        dfpoly[i,4] <- mean(diff(y)/diff(x))
}
names(dfpoly) <- c("x length","y min","y max","y slope")
dfpoly
```

This prints

```
  x length y min y max y slope
1       21     0     1       1
2      101     0     1       1
3      201     0     1       1
4     1001     0     1       1
5     2001     0     1       1
6    10001     0     1       1
```